# How to recreate a boxplot (from Python) in Tableau

Tags: types, tableau-api, visualization, boxplot

I am trying to recreate a boxplot in Tableau that I have built successfully in Python.

[The y axis has scores in the form of quintiles (1-5).The x axis has identity scores from -1.5 to 1.82](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHdgF.jpg)

What I need from the boxplot is the outlier groups that are revealed (High scores/Low identity and High identity/low scores).

I am not able to recreate this in Tableau (the platform I have to present my results in). After following this step by step https://evolytics.com/blog/tableau-201-make-box-whisker-plot/ this is what I get:

[Same axes as above, just one large boxplot that does not reveal any specific data points.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3HQN.jpg)

Does anyone know how I can adjust my datatypes or somehow make this boxplot work?
I appreciate the help as I have spent hours on this already.

Comment: a box plot of the form you want required discrete values on the X-axis (rows). On thing to try is to right click the rows pill and select "discrete". IF this doesn't work try creating bins of values for this axis and using the bins rather than the raw values for the axis.

Comment: Thanks so much @matt_black for responding. 

[This][1] is what I get when I make "math identity" discrete. They are kind of like bins. 

I wonder how I can disaggregate the data somehow to be able to show the outliers. Any ideas?


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UjUU.png

Comment: This looks as though you have made both axes discrete. Te effect you want needs one discrete and theo other continuous.